# Crafting an ICMP packet inside a Linux kernel Module

Tags: linux, network-programming, linux-kernel

I'm tring to experiment with the ICMP protocol and have created a  kernel-module for linux that analyses ICMP packet ( Processes the packet only if if the ICMP code field is a magic number ) . Now to test this module , i have to create a an ICMP packet and send it to the host where this analysing module is running  . In fact it would be nice if i could implement it the kernel itself (as a module ) . I am looking for something like a packetcrafter in kernel , I googled it found a lot of articles explaining the lifetime of a packet , rather than tutorials of creating it . User space packetcrafters would be my last resort, that too those  which are highly flexible like where i'll be able to set ICMP code etc . And I'm not wary of kernel panics :-) !!!!!  Any packet crafting ideas are welcome .

Comment: Check the source of the netfilter modules, where they generate icmp responses like for blocked ports. But as Adel said below, I'd use raw sockets from outer user space, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sir, I strongly advice you against using the kernel module to build ICMP packets.

You can use user-space raw-sockets to craft ICMP packets, even build the IP-header itself byte by byte.
So you can get as flexible as it can get using that.

Please, take a look at this

```
ip = (struct iphdr*) packet;
    icmp = (struct icmphdr*) (packet + sizeof(struct iphdr));

    /*  
     *  here the ip packet is set up except checksum
     */
    ip->ihl         = 5;
    ip->version         = 4;
    ip->tos         = 0;
    ip->tot_len         = sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct icmphdr);
    ip->id          = htons(random());
    ip->ttl         = 255;
    ip->protocol        = IPPROTO_ICMP;
    ip->saddr           = inet_addr(src_addr);
    ip->daddr           = inet_addr(dst_addr);


    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP)) == -1)
    {
    perror("socket");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* 
     *  IP_HDRINCL must be set on the socket so that
     *  the kernel does not attempt to automatically add
     *  a default ip header to the packet
     */

    setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &optval, sizeof(int));

    /*
     *  here the icmp packet is created
     *  also the ip checksum is generated
     */
    icmp->type          = ICMP_ECHO;
    icmp->code          = 0;
    icmp->un.echo.id        = 0;
    icmp->un.echo.sequence  = 0;
    icmp->checksum      = 0;
    icmp-> checksum     = in_cksum((unsigned short *)icmp, sizeof(struct icmphdr));

    ip->check           = in_cksum((unsigned short *)ip, sizeof(struct iphdr));
```

If this part of code looks flexible enough, then read about raw sockets :D maybe they're the easiest and safest answer to your need.

Please check the following links for further info 
http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs4254/fall04/slides/raw_6.pdf
http://www.cs.binghamton.edu/~steflik/cs455/rawip.txt
http://cboard.cprogramming.com/networking-device-communication/107801-linux-raw-socket-programming.html    a very nice topic, pretty useful imo

Comment: The prospect of raw sockets seems to be something worth a test . I'll choose the raw sockets on the trial basis for now,but readers do post tutorials on packet crafting in kernel space if you've seen them anywhere . Obviously i'll come back and write a kernel space    packet crafter And thanks Adel- for something new and exciting

Answer (score 0):

You can try [libcrafter](http://code.google.com/p/libcrafter/) for packet crafting on user space. Is very easy to use! The library is able to craft or decode packets of most common networks protocols, send them on the wire, capture them and match requests and replies.

For example, the next code craft and send an ICMP packet:

```
string MyIP = GetMyIP("eth0");

/* Create an IP header */
IP ip_header;

/* Set the Source and Destination IP address */
ip_header.SetSourceIP(MyIP);                      
ip_header.SetDestinationIP("1.2.3.4"); 

/* Create an ICMP header */
ICMP icmp_header;

icmp_header.SetType(ICMP::EchoRequest);
icmp_header.SetIdentifier(RNG16());

/* Create a packet... */
Packet packet = ip_header / icmp_header;

packet.Send();
```

Why you want to craft an ICMP packet on kernel-space? Just for fun? :-p

Answer (score 0):

Linux kernel includes a packet generator tool **pktgen** for testing the network with pre-configured packets. Source code for this module resides in net/core/pktgen.c